# django when I save a model, a group is not assigned to it

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

when I save to a group is not assigned to the user.

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    if self.is_active: 
        group = Group.objects.get(name = 'test')   
        self.groups.add(group)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the parent instance first and then add an instance to a ManyToMany relation:

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.is_active: 
        group = Group.objects.get(name = 'test')   
        self.groups.add(group)
    return self
```

You can also use signals and `post_save` signal to be specific which might be a cleaner way of doing this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=YourModel)
def add_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active: 
        group = Group.objects.get(name = 'test')   
        instance.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: sender is model. My model is AbstractUser. My model is name Profil not defined for receiver

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean. All you need to do for the receiver example is to change `YourModel` with the model you are trying to add the group to after calling save. If it's called `Profile`, then just import it in the file and replace `YourModel` with `Profile`.

Comment: And where do I add that part of the code to models.py or signals.py and how do I call it?

Comment: It can be anywhere you want. just don't forget the imports. And you don't need to call it anywhere. It will just work. you can read more about signals here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/

Comment: it works but it doesn't work instance.groups.add(group)

Comment: You mean it doesn't add the group? If the model is set properly, it has to work. there is nothing special about it really. if the `add_group` signal is called, then the problem has to be somewhere else. check the condition: `instance.is_active`.

Comment: verified when creating a new user it works, but when editing a user it doesn't work

Comment: You are probably using `.update()`. `.update()` doesn't call `save()` method so your `post_save()` signal won't be called either. So you either have to use save method instead while updating (`instance.field = "new value"` and then call `instance.save()`) or you have to override the update method if you're updating your instance like this: `instance.update(field="new value")`.

Comment: update your instance like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects . don't use `.update()`

Comment: I really don't know how to do it. I have signals.py but I really have no idea how to edit when I edit and save the model